# Is it possible to import a test to another file using jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is it possible to import a test to another file using jest?

I need to create a file to use as a "test suite", using some tests from different files with the idea of ​​having a smoke test suite.

For example:

File 1:

```js
describe('Test 1', function () {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    data = await csv().fromFile(
      './src/data/test.csv',
    );
  });

  it('Test 1.1', async function () {
    const testObject = await doSomething(data);

    expect(Array.isArray(testObject)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

File 2:

```js
describe('Test 2', function () {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    data = await csv().fromFile(
      './src/data/test.csv',
    );
  });

  it('Test 2.1', async function () {
    const testObject = await doSomething(data);

    expect(Array.isArray(testObject)).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Test Suite:

*A file to run tests 1.1 and 2.1.*